# Live paint bucket tool filling wrong space Ai CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6, paint

I am trying to fill the white space in my art work using live paint. I select all of the art work and click in the space I want it to fill but it seems to only give me the option of filling the little black lines (see images below) instead of the white space around it I want to fill.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The white (chest) area is not part of the selection. Therefore It *won't* be part of the Live Paint group and won't be filled.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the white area is empty and you want to create a shape which fills it. Your black frame around the white area has a gap or some part of it is not selected. The problem can be seen in the bottom. It looks like a black line is out of the selection.

[image]

If there was a piece which is not a path you would get a warning dialog.

I have wrestled with the same problem like an idiot when I forgot I had locked some parts. Check the Layers panel is there locked objects.

BTW. Live paint can accept also gaps. See Live Paint Gap options.